# Mongodb text index search using refrence document inside of the text indexed document

Tags: full-text-indexing

I have a shop document that has a reference for a product docuemnt

```
shop:{
product_id:ObjectId(...)
.
.
.
}
```

how to use text index for product document fields inside of shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was, there is no such a way to use text indexing for refrenced documents.

which leads to embedding them inside of the document we wish to apply text-indexing for